# Ubuntu Software Center won't open to allow download of fonts

Tags: software-center

I need to download the Times New Roman font onto my Libreoffice writer. When I go to follow the steps on the Ubuntu Software Center, I click on the icon and it opens to a loading circle and then closes by itself and will not open. HELP!

Comment: What's the name of the file that you're trying to download?

Comment: I'm putting this in a comment since it doesn't answer your larger question about the SWC. To install MS fonts without SWC: 1) Open a terminal with ctrl-alt-t 2) type `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` 3) You will see a msg box asking you to accept the license. Be sure to follow the instructions.

Comment: Im trying to download microsoft core fonts. I opened a terminal and it said
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_universe_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Ubuntu Software Center. Open up Synaptic and search for 'Software'. Ubuntu Software Center is listed as 'Software Center'. Right click on it and choose reinistall then apply.

Comment: Where can I find Synaptic?